# How to get specific node value in JSON array by key value

Tags: c#, json, .net, vb.net, json.net

Using **JSON.NET**. How do you identify a value from another element in the node?

In this example how would the **value** *(e.g 22)* in the node where **key = "b"** be read?

*(Assume "b" is unique or get first instance only)*

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "key": "a",
            "value": "11"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "key": "b",
            "value": "22"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "key": "c",
            "value": "33"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm assuming it's necessary to loop over each array item for key = "b" and read the value in that iteration unless there is a way to directly target the node based on key?

**VB - NON WORKING EXAMPLE**

The json has already been deserialised into object

```
Dim Results As Batch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Batch)(response)

For Each item In Results.data.Where(Function(obj) obj("key").Value(Of String)() = "b")
   Dim DataVal as String = obj("value").Value
Next
```

Comment: Do you want a solution in c# or vb.net?  I'm not that familiar with VB but this might work: `Dim items = Results.data.Where(Function(i) i.key = "b")` which will get all items with `key == "b"`.  If you only want the first item you could try: `Dim item = Results.data.FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.key = "b")`

Comment: Directly with `var firstFromValue = JToken.Parse(response)["data"].FirstOrDefault(d => d["key"] == "b")` or `Dim firstFromValue = JToken.Parse(response)("data").FirstOrDefault(Function(d) d("key") = "b")`

Comment: @haldo Thanks for the suggestion. I am working in vb but answer can be in either. How does your answer reference the "value" node?

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the suggestion but how does this reference ths value field?

Comment: Just add `.value` to my second query (using FirstOrDefault()) to get the value field, or iterate through the first query (which is IEnumerable) and use `.value` to get the value from that

Comment: `dim value = key("value").ToString()` or `string value = key["value"].ToString();` or `int value = key["value"].ToObject<int>);`, if you want to convert immediately -- I suggest to deserialize your JSON to .Net classes, so you can access their strongly typed members as usual. You can use [QiuckType](https://app.quicktype.io/) to generate classes in C# or [Json Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) in VB.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim firstFromValue = JToken.Parse(response)("data").FirstOrDefault(Function(d) d("key") = "b").value
```